# Using a Monadic eDSL from the REPL

Tags: haskell, monads, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

Say I have created myself an embedded domain specific language in Haskell using a monad. For example a simple language that lets you push and pop values on a stack, implemented using the state monad:

```
type DSL a = State [Int] a

push :: Int -> DSL ()
pop :: DSL Int
```

Now I can write small stack manipulation programs using do notation:

```
program = do
    push 10
    push 20
    a <- pop
    push (5*a)
    return a
```

However, I would really like to use my DSL interactively from a REPL (GHCi in particular, willing to use other if it would help).

Unfortunately having a session like:

```
>push 10
>pop
10
>push 100
```

Does not immediately work, which is probably rather reasonable. However I really think being able to do something with a similar feel to that would be cool. The way the state monad work does not lend itself easily to this. You need to build up your `DSL a` type and then evaluate it.

Is there a way to do something like this. Incrementally using a monad in the REPL?

I have been looking at things like [operational](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational), [MonadPrompt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadPrompt), and [MonadCont](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Cont.html) which I sort of get the feeling maybe could be used to do something like this. Unfortunately none of the examples I have seen addresses this particular problem.

Comment: Write a parser for your language and run your own REPL?

Comment: You certainly can't do this for arbitrary monads. What if the monad in question was `data Proxy a = Proxy`? What would you print when someone runs a `Proxy` computation at the prompt?

Comment: @Zeta That is something I have thought about, but then it would no longer be an *embedded* DSL. Sometimes that is what you want, and I asked this question to see if it was possible to use an embedded DSL from the REPL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To an extent.

I don't believe it can be done for arbitrary Monads/instruction sets, but here's something that would work for your example. I'm using [operational](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational) with an IORef to back the REPL state.

```
data DSLInstruction a where
    Push :: Int -> DSLInstruction ()
    Pop :: DSLInstruction Int

type DSL a = Program DSLInstruction a

push :: Int -> DSL ()
push n = singleton (Push n)

pop :: DSL Int
pop = singleton Pop

-- runDslState :: DSL a -> State [Int] a
-- runDslState = ...

runDslIO :: IORef [Int] -> DSL a -> IO a
runDslIO ref m = case view m of
    Return a -> return a
    Push n :>>= k -> do
        modifyIORef ref (n :)
        runDslIO ref (k ())
    Pop :>>= k -> do
        n <- atomicModifyIORef ref (\(n : ns) -> (ns, n))
        runDslIO ref (k n)

replSession :: [Int] -> IO (Int -> IO (), IO Int)
replSession initial = do
    ref <- newIORef initial
    let pushIO n = runDslIO ref (push n)
        popIO = runDslIO ref pop
    (pushIO, popIO)
```

Then you can use it like:

```
> (push, pop) <- replSession [] -- this shadows the DSL push/pop definitions
> push 10
> pop
10
> push 100
```

It should be straightforward to use this technique for State/Reader/Writer/IO-based DSLs. I don't expect it to work for everything though.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to re-simulate the whole history each time you do anything.  This will work for any pure monad.  Here's an extemporaneous library for it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.IORef
import Data.Proxy

newtype REPL m f = REPL { run :: forall a. m a -> IO (f a) }

newREPL :: (Monad m) => Proxy m -> (forall a. m a -> f a) -> IO (REPL m f)
newREPL _ runM = do
    accum <- newIORef (return ())
    return $ REPL (\nextAction -> do
        actions <- readIORef accum
        writeIORef accum (actions >> nextAction >> return ())
        return (runM (actions >> nextAction)))
```

Basically, it stores all the actions run thus far in an `IORef`, and each time you do something it adds to the list of actions and runs it from the top.

To create a repl, use `newREPL`, passing it a `Proxy` for the monad and a "run" function that gets you out of the monad.  The reason the run function has type `m a -> f a` instead of `m a -> a` is so that you can include extra information in the output -- for example, you might want to view the current state, too, in which case you could use an `f` like:

```
data StateOutput a = StateOutput a [Int]
    deriving (Show)
```

But I have just used it with [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.2.2.1/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html) which does nothing special.

The `Proxy` argument is so that ghci's defaulting doesn't bite us when we create a new repl instance.

Here's how you use it:

```
>>> repl <- newREPL (Proxy :: Proxy DSL) (\m -> Identity (evalState m []))
>>> run repl $ push 1
Identity ()
>>> run repl $ push 2
Identity ()
>>> run repl $ pop
Identity 2
>>> run repl $ pop
Identity 1
```

If the extra `Identity` line noise bothers you, you could use your own functor:

```
newtype LineOutput a = LineOutput a
instance (Show a) => Show (LineOutput a) where
    show (LineOutput x) = show x
```

There was one small change I had to make -- I had to change

```
type DSL a = State [Int] a
```

to

```
type DSL = State [Int]
```

because you can't use type synonyms that are not fully applied, like when I said `Proxy :: DSL`.  The latter, I think, is more idiomatic anyway.